# Logstash pipeline error: error registering jdbc plugin

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

When I first created Logstash jdbc conf file to import my MySQL data to Elasticsearch, it was working good. But, suddenly, the same files which worked okay, are not working any more and giving an error "Error registering plugin".

Here is my `sms-logstash.conf` file

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sms"
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => ""
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    # our query
    statement => "SELECT * FROM salon_reg" 

    }
  }

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }

  elasticsearch {
  "hosts" => "localhost:9200"
  "index" => "sms"
  "document_type" => "salon_reg"


  }


}
```

When I run this command as `bin/logstash -f sms-logstash.conf`

It gives the following error

```
C:\Users\robesh\Downloads\logstash-6.2.3\logstash-6.2.3\bin>logstash -f sms-logstash.conf
Sending Logstash's logs to C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2018-04-15T15:05:46,900][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2018-04-15T15:05:47,028][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2018-04-15T15:05:47,665][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2018-04-15T15:05:49,635][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.2.3"}
[2018-04-15T15:05:51,303][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2018-04-15T15:06:04,935][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] You are using a deprecated config setting "document_type" set in elasticsearch. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future. Document types are being deprecated in Elasticsearch 6.0, and removed entirely in 7.0. You should avoid this feature If you have any questions about this, please visit the #logstash channel on freenode irc. {:name=>"document_type", :plugin=><LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch hosts=>[//localhost:9200], index=>"sms", document_type=>"salon_reg", id=>"7eecf64f77b050d7ebba1e645e2de1d988a4f3d4b88814c75044d6e6c4606a2b", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_cbc6f6b2-287c-44bf-8771-3a951d7ceabf", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, workers=>1, manage_template=>true, template_name=>"logstash", template_overwrite=>false, doc_as_upsert=>false, script_type=>"inline", script_lang=>"painless", script_var_name=>"event", scripted_upsert=>false, retry_initial_interval=>2, retry_max_interval=>64, retry_on_conflict=>1, action=>"index", ssl_certificate_verification=>true, sniffing=>false, sniffing_delay=>5, timeout=>60, pool_max=>1000, pool_max_per_route=>100, resurrect_delay=>5, validate_after_inactivity=>10000, http_compression=>false>}
[2018-04-15T15:06:05,141][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2018-04-15T15:06:06,405][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2018-04-15T15:06:06,426][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2018-04-15T15:06:07,079][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2018-04-15T15:06:07,280][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
[2018-04-15T15:06:07,289][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
[2018-04-15T15:06:07,336][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2018-04-15T15:06:07,424][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2018-04-15T15:06:07,533][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[2018-04-15T15:06:08,863][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Error registering plugin {:pipeline_id=>"main", :plugin=>"<LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc jdbc_connection_string=>\"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sms\", jdbc_user=>\"root\", jdbc_driver_library=>\"C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar\", jdbc_driver_class=>\"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\", statement=>\"SELECT * FROM salon_reg\", id=>\"0c99246377cb88117db974a51d7bdcb982e8fe882ab825575c8ebdc3c890fb5a\", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>\"plain_d687f831-1ac5-4480-b23d-e7fc976f5e9a\", enable_metric=>true, charset=>\"UTF-8\">, jdbc_paging_enabled=>false, jdbc_page_size=>100000, jdbc_validate_connection=>false, jdbc_validation_timeout=>3600, jdbc_pool_timeout=>5, sql_log_level=>\"info\", connection_retry_attempts=>1, connection_retry_attempts_wait_time=>0.5, last_run_metadata_path=>\"C:\\\\Users\\\\robesh/.logstash_jdbc_last_run\", use_column_value=>false, tracking_column_type=>\"numeric\", clean_run=>false, record_last_run=>true, lowercase_column_names=>true>", :error=>"(<unknown>): 'reader' unacceptable code point '\u0000' (0x0) special characters are not allowed\nin \"'reader'\", position 0 at line 0 column 0", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x1ad70417 run>"}
[2018-04-15T15:06:09,386][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): 'reader' unacceptable code point ' ' (0x0) special characters are not allowed
in "'reader'", position 0 at line 0 column 0>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/ext/psych/PsychParser.java:231:in `parse'", "uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/psych.rb:377:in `parse_stream'", "uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/psych.rb:325:in `parse'", "uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/psych.rb:252:in `load'", "C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.5/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/value_tracking.rb:102:in `read'", "C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.5/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/value_tracking.rb:78:in `get_initial'", "C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.5/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/value_tracking.rb:36:in `initialize'", "C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.5/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/value_tracking.rb:29:in `build_last_value_tracker'", "C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.5/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:216:in `register'", "C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:341:in `register_plugin'", "C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:352:in `block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'", "C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:352:in `register_plugins'", "C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:502:in `start_inputs'", "C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:393:in `start_workers'", "C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:289:in `run'", "C:/Users/robesh/Downloads/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-6.2.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:249:in `block in start'"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x1ad70417 run>"}
[2018-04-15T15:06:09,506][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}

C:\Users\robesh\Downloads\logstash-6.2.3\logstash-6.2.3\bin>
```

The interesting thing here is that this same file was working fine previously and it indexed my data nicely to Elasticsearch, but suddenly now its giving an error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an encoding problem, ensure that the logstash file has UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I don't know much about the elasticsearch and logstash files. Can you tell me in more details how should I do that?

Comment: The encoding of the file is not related to logstash but is related to the text editor that you are using to edit and save the files. If you use notepad++ for example, you can choose the file encoding. It might be an encoding problem because i see this in your error: ' ' (0x0) special characters are not allowed

Comment: Yea, I am using notepad++ and checked that it's encoded UTF-8. So what do you say? should I keep it like this or remove the encoding?

Comment: The encoding is correct. Ensure also that only ascii character are utilized.

Comment: There are two options for characters

Comment: 1: ASCII -> HEX  2: HEX-> ASCII. What should I choose?

Comment: use the second and see if the error message change.

Comment: Do you think the problem could be in 'pipeline.yml' file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your config is correct :

```
bin/logstash --config.test_and_exit -f <path_to_config_file>
```

If your config is valid, then looks at $USER_HOME/.logstash_jdbc_last_run file, probably that file exists but isn't valid YAML. Fix what's broken about the file, or just delete it.